# How to set ContextMenu of a bound item?

Tags: wpf, styles, contextmenu, listboxitem, setter

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Name="mnuEdit" Header="_Edit" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
<Style>
```

But it throws the following exception:

```
Cannot add content of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu'
to an object of type 'System.Object'.
Error at object 'System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu'
in markup file blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="contextMenu">
    <MenuItem Name="mnuEdit" Header="_Edit" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
</ContextMenu>

<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{DynamicResource contextMenu}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: ok, but why? Other properties are settable without using a Static or Dynamic Resource.

Comment: @jrwren, Good point.  My _guess_ is that if you do it the way it's shown in the question then a context menu is created per-menu item, which is potentially wasteful when you only need one.  I know that's not a conclusive explanation though.

Comment: I would love a concrete answer. Knowing why would definitely help my understanding of WPF.