# C# - wpf - Cannot add ContextMenu to ListView since Framework Downgrade

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I got the following code in my xaml file:

```
...
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ContextMenu>
                    ...
...
```

If I run the application in debug mode I get a **System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException** at the **ContextMenu** with an additional information as follows:

German original:

> Additional information: Einem Objekt vom Typ "System.Object" kann kein
>   Inhalt vom Typ "System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu" hinzugefügt
>   werden.

My english translation (I dont know the original english message):

> Additional information: You cannot add content of the type "System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu" to an object of the type "System.Object".

I ported the application from .NET4.0 down to .NET3.5 for compatibility reasons. In .NET4.0 it worked without problems.

**What's the problem and how to solve this?**

Further information:

- IDE: Visual Studio Community 2015
- .NET 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    <ContextMenu x:Key="contextMenu">
    <MenuItem Name="mnuEdit" Header="_Edit" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
</ContextMenu>
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{DynamicResource contextMenu}" />
</Style>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397497/how-to-set-contextmenu-of-a-bound-item)

Comment: My ContextMenu does not offer a **x:Key**.

Comment: **Update:** Ok; I didn't understand your solution the first time. Now I put the contextMenu in some **Window.Resources** and replaced the old one with the new setter. It works now; thanks.